# How to give windows form project a windows 8 look?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms, windows-8

I'm using VS2010
and i would like to know how to make my form have the style of windows 8 forms

Answer (score 3):

I have used this in the past and it gives a very metro look.. its also very easy to use.

https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui

hope that helps

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

That is not determined by Visual Studio. It is determined by the [Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager), hence it depends on which Windows version you are running.

EDIT: If you are referring to wanting to develop Metro applications in a Windows version other than Windows 8, then the answer is: no, you cannot. You must use Windows 8 for that task. There may be frameworks that exist that mimic the style, however, they are by no means native.

Comment: Not strictly true, as you *could* owner-draw the frame...

Answer (score 0):

you can use Wpf, entire windows 8 look is based on Wpf only

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this? it sounds completely wrong to me. Win7 wpf apps dont automatically have win8 borders.

Comment: which borders are you talking about ? you can change control template of the control and can get any look